# Column Vector in a subscript?

Tags: fontsize, matrices, subscripts

I'm trying to write the point (2,1) as a column vector in a subscript. I tried

```
 P_{\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\  1 \end{matrix}}
```

But this gave me a matrix in the subscript that is the same size as a 2x1 matrix normally is. How can I make this matrix subscript sized?

Comment: `P_{\left(\substack{2 \\ 1}\right)}` ? Welcome to TeX. SE!

Comment: For answer with example, how my suggestion work with image of `P_{...}` , please provide small, complete document with `\documentclass{...}` at the beginning and with `\end{document} at the end, called Minimal Working Example (MWE).

Answer (score 4):

Use `psmallmatrix` from the `mathtools` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$P_{\begin{psmallmatrix} 2 \\  1 \end{psmallmatrix}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably use `\scriptscriptstyle` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\vsub}[1]{%
  \left(\begin{smallsmallmatrix}#1\end{smallsmallmatrix}\right)%
}

% borrow from amsmath.sty
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{smallsmallmatrix}{\null\vcenter\bgroup
  \Let@\restore@math@cr\default@tag
  \baselineskip4\ex@ \lineskip1.5\ex@ \lineskiplimit\lineskip
  \ialign\bgroup\hfil$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil&&\thickspace\hfil
  $\m@th\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil\crcr
}{%
  \crcr\egroup\egroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
P_{\vsub{2 \\ 1}}+Q_{\vsub{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]